# Scala Regex Pattern Matching

Tags: regex, scala

I need to use a regex to match a pattern in Scala and I currently have a Regex that is

```
InputPattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = put (.*) in (.*)
```

When I run the follwing this happens:

```
scala> val InputPattern(verb, item, prep, obj) = "put a in b";
scala.MatchError: put a in b (of class java.lang.String)
... 33 elided
```

I would like it to end up with `verb("put"), item("a"), prep("in"), and obj("b")` for input **"put a in b"** and also `verb("put"), item(""), prep("in"), and obj("")` for input **"put in"**.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you need a pattern with 4 capturing groups, e.g. `(?m)^(\S*)\s*(\S*?)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*?)$`. Have a look at the demo: https://regex101.com/r/mC5eI5/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your special cases :

```
scala> val InputPattern = "(put) (.*?) ?(in) ?(.*?)".r
InputPattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = (put) (.*) ?(in) ?(.*)

scala> val InputPattern(verb, item, prep, obj) = "put a in b"
verb: String = put
item: String = a
prep: String = in
obj: String = b

scala> val InputPattern(verb, item, prep, obj) = "put in"
verb: String = put
item: String = ""
prep: String = in
obj: String = ""
```

`put` and `in` here are also captured in groups to participate in pattern matching. I also used lazy regexps `(.*?)` to capture as less as possible, you may replace it with `(\S*)`. `?` gives you optional space to match 
"put in" (with one space between `put` and `in` and no space at the end).

But be aware of this:

```
scala> val InputPattern(verb, item, prep, obj) = "put ainb"
verb: String = put
item: String = a
prep: String = in
obj: String = b

scala> val InputPattern(verb, item, prep, obj) = "put aininb"
verb: String = put
item: String = a
prep: String = in
obj: String = inb

scala> val InputPattern(verb, item, prep, obj) = "put ain"
verb: String = put
item: String = a
prep: String = in
obj: String = ""
```

If you have simple command interpreter it may be even good, otherwise you should match your special cases separately.

To process a simple (not natural) language, you may also consider `StandardTokenParsers`, as they are context-free ([Chomsky type 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)):

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._

val p = new StandardTokenParsers {
   lexical.reserved ++= List("put", "in") 
   def p = "put" ~ opt(ident) ~ "in" ~ opt(ident)
}

scala> p.p(new p.lexical.Scanner("put a in b"))
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res13 = [1.11] parsed: (((put~Some(a))~in)~Some(b))

scala> p.p(new p.lexical.Scanner("put in"))
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res14 = [1.7] parsed: (((put~None)~in)~None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write one regexp for all cases, but I'm not sure it would be readable and maintainable. I prefer simple approach:

```
val pattern1 = "(put) (.*) (in) (.*)".r
val pattern2 = "(put) (in)".r
def parse(text: String) = text match { 
  case pattern1(verb, item, prep, obj) => (verb, item, prep, obj); 
  case pattern2(verb, prep) => (verb, "", prep, "") 
}
scala> parse("put a in b")
res6: (String, String, String, String) = (put,a,in,b)

scala> parse("put in")
res7: (String, String, String, String) = (put,"",in,"")
```

And one extra notion: I hope you know what you are doing! RegEx is a [Chomsky Type 3 grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) and natural language is much more complex. If you need natural language parser, you can use already available solution such as [Stanford NLP parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml).

Comment: Thank you! Although this works the other answer worked out better in my code. Thanks for the "extra notion" but this is just for a simple College Assignment with a list of given commands with variables. It's my first time doing Scala and I was just running into some slight issues with my RegEx.